# Is it possible to play sound in mono?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, audio

I'm in a workplace that only allows one headphone in. This makes some music pretty awful, only having one channel. I'd like to mix my audio into one channel, but this seems to be a bit more difficult than you would expect. I don't want to buy a paid app, and I'm playing music from my Google Music library, so alternate players aren't an option.

Is there any way to do this digitally? I don't want to have to buy an adapter and have it sticking out of my phone, risking my headphone jack, just to play mono.

I'm on a Droid X2 running CM9. I know some of the manufacturer ROMs had mono options, but it's not in stock Android or CM9.

Comment: Do they make you cut your headphones in half?!

Comment: Haha no, but it's open cubes and I'm visible from the elevator lobby, so I'd rather not be breaking any rules.

Comment: This is very relevant for those of us who are deaf in one ear!

Answer (score 4):

There's a  setting under  accessibility options for mono audio.  I  haven't tried it yet,  but it may be what you want.

Comment: I'm not seeing this. It might be a feature in Jelly Bean or a proprietary feature to your ROM.

Comment: I've tried this on mine (a Samsung Galaxy Win Duos) with DoubleTwist just before I saw this question and it didn't made the playback mono. :S I have to avoid Play Music now, because it downloads music to the internal storage (Built-in acts as SD) instead of the external one (MicroSD card).

Comment: This worked for me on the HTC One M9, Android 5.1, HTC Sense 7.0.
Tested in Spotify and Poweramp. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Poweramp](http://powerampapp.com). It has tons of sound settings including a mono option.

Comment: Yes, but that is a paid app. I suppose I should have specified that I don't want to pay.

Also, I'm using Google Music, so I believe this is out of the question. I'll edit to specify more.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of bluetooth headsets only play mono sounds, though you generally won't get the sound quality as you do from a wired headset.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit of an audiophile and I couldn't stand bluetooth. I also have 10-hour work days, and I don't think my bluetooth headset would last the day.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but you can purchase a mono earphone that sends both audio channels to one earbud.  Search eBay for " mono (earbud,earphone) "

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to it without having to buy anything. You'll have to get root permissions on your ROM and might be permissive SELinux.

Install Viper's Audio for Android latest version from http://vipersaudio.com/blog/?page_id=48

Launch the app, and install a driver with any quality you need, then reboot!
After rebooting your device, launch Viper's Audio app again, insert your headphone in then do some setup:

On Headset tab, there is a FIELD SURROND feature options. Enable it, and select some Field Surround Strength and Mid Image Strength values (I recommend you to set both of them to Slight). All this will give you that mono sound, bouncing the sound from one channel to another, with a minimal delay!

**(OPTIONAL -> NOT NECESSARY!)** After this, on the very bottom of this list, you should find MASTER GATE (LIMITER) options, and you can set Channel Pan to 1.0 : .0 or vice versa.

All this won't give u a true mono mixdown, but it sounds good enough, and
I don't really think you're seeking some hi quality audio, cause music made to be heard in stereo.
Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

One can use ffmpeg:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -ac 1 out.avi
avconv -i input.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -ac 1 out.avi
```

Comment: This does not apply, since the OP mentions he's playing music from Google Music, not from local files.

Answer (score -2):

try [Boeffla sound control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.near.boefflasound) app.